# FadeIn div on scroll inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thats my script:

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 70,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

With this one, I am able to fadeIn a "menu"-div, when I scroll down inside the <>body<>. Now I want the same by scrolling inside a "wrapper"-div. At the moment the "menu"-div doesn´t fadeIn when I scroll down inside the "wrapper"-div, because I dont scroll the <>body<>.

So, my question: is there a simple way to add beside the <>body<>-scroll also the "wrapper"-div scroll, to fadeIn the same "menu"-div at this script?

Thats the classie.js:

```
/*!
 * classie v1.0.1
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false, module: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
  // CommonJS
  module.exports = classie;
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Comment: Try to add `scroll` event to that element. For example. `element.addEventListener('scroll', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#wrapper').scroll(function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 70,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a no-Classie version:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#wrapper').scroll(function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 70,
            header = $("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            header.addClass("smaller");
        } else {
            if (header.hasClass("smaller")) {
                header.removeClass("smaller");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I try it at the moment ... do not look like it works ;(.

Comment: Does your wrapper element have an ID = wrapper?

Comment: @Pepe perhaps your distanceY is not correctly calculated. Add console.log('HERE'); just before "var distanceY =" and you will see the code was called when you tried scrolling inside the wrapper.

Comment: @Pepe Please try my no-Classie version.

Comment: @Pepe please post your code on JsFiddle with HTML and CSS so I can see how it works.